# nodejs bigquery parameterised query inside IN() expression

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am trying to run a parameterised query using the npm module `@google-cloud/bigquery`.
Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IN (@ids);
```

I have no idea how bigQuery is expecting the parameter ids formatted.

My `options.params` look like something like this:

```
{ ids: '"1234", "4567"'}
```

But I don't get any result back. I know there are results, I can see them in bigquery and if I remove the parameter and just inject the string works just fine.

It seem pretty easy, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work, anyone who is willing to help me out?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think that you need to pass the argument as { ids: '1234, 4567'}. In other words, the ids should be single string that separated by comma.

Comment: thank you @Dashzeveg I am pretty sure I tried that too, but didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Of course I found the solution as soon as I posted the question...
Thanks to [this thread](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/9197779?hl=en)! Need to do some gymnastic...

So provided that the parameter is a string like:

```
'1234,5678'
```

We need to do:

```
WHERE id IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(@ids,"[0-9a-zA-Z]+"))
```

REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL - returns an array

UNNEST - flattens the array for the IN clause as stated in the link above.